# Python ModuleNotFoundError. Probably a simple mistake

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to setup up some test cases using pytest for a project i'm working on and have setup my directory like so.

```
C:.
│   OpenGLTestCase.py
│   Sprite.py
│   SpriteManager.py
│   SpriteRenderer.py
│   Texture.py
│   __init__.py
│
├───.pytest_cache
│   │   .gitignore
│   │   CACHEDIR.TAG
│   │   README.md
│   │
│   └───v
│       └───cache
│               lastfailed
│               nodeids
│               stepwise
│
├───tests
│   │   colorGrid.png
│   │   OpenGLTestCaseExample.py
│   │   OpenGLTestCaseExample2.py
│   │   test.png
│   │   test.svg
│   │   test2.png
│   │   test3.png
│   │   test_over_colorGrid_at_128left_256_top.png
│   │   test_over_uvGrid_at_128left_256_top.png
│   │   test_render_image_expected.png
│   │   test_render_triangle_expected.png
│   │   test_sprite_manager.py
│   │   test_Texture.py
│   │   uvGrid.png
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           test_sprite_manager.cpython-37-pytest-5.0.0.pyc
│           test_sprite_manager.cpython-37-PYTEST.pyc
│           test_Texture.cpython-37-pytest-5.0.0.pyc
│           test_Texture.cpython-37-PYTEST.pyc
│
└───__pycache__
        OpenGLTestCase.cpython-37.pyc
        Sprite.cpython-37.pyc
        SpriteManager.cpython-37.pyc
        SpriteRenderer.cpython-37.pyc
        Texture.cpython-37.pyc
        __init__.cpython-37.pyc
```

The parent folder that holds all of this is called "pygameOpenGLUtil". I have my main 4 files in the highest directory along with my `__init__.py`.  When I try and run pytest at this level it says throws a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygameOpenGLUtil'". This thrown in my test_sprite_manager.py file. I've gotten this to work in other projects before but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this one I am sure i'm just forgetting something small.

Here is my `__init__.py`:

```
from .OpenGLTestCase import *
from .Sprite import *
from .SpriteManager import *
from .SpriteRenderer import *
from .Texture import *
```

And here is my test_sprite_manager.py:

```
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *
from pygameOpenGLUtil import *

class SpriteManagerTest(OpenGLTestCase):
    def test_add_sprite(self):
        test_sprite_map = SpriteManager()
        test_sprite_one = Sprite(test_sprite_map)
        test_sprite_one = Sprite(test_sprite_map)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I am running python3.7.3 and pytest version 5.0.0